# Push object into queue

Tags: c++, class, object, queue

I have a class below.

How do i write something to the class say i want to write to all those fields in private, after i do that how do i push them into the queue and then read them out of the queue?

Thanks!

```
class PCB
{
    public:
        void setPID (int a)
        {
            PID = a;
        }
        int retrievePID()
        {
            return PID;
        }
        void setFilename (string input)
        {
            Filename = input;
        }
        string retrieveFilename()
        {
            return Filename;
        }
        void setMemstart (int a)
        {
            Memstart = a;
        }
        int retrieveMemstart()
        {
            return Memstart;
        }
        void setRW (char a)
        {
            rw = a;
        }
        int retrieveRW()
        {
            return rw;
        }
        void setFilelength (string input)
        {
            Filelength = input;
        }
        string retrieveFilelength()
        {
            return Filelength;
        }

    private:
        int PID;
        string Filename;
        int Memstart;
        char rw;
        string Filelength;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To edit values:

```
PCB myPCB;
myPCB.setPID(3);
myPCB.setFilename("myFile.pcb");
```

To push values onto the stack:

```
std::stack<PCB> mystack;
mystack.push(myPCB);
```

To view and pop `PCB`s:

```
PCB topPCB = mystack.top();
mystack.pop();
```